# R create multipanel pdf with identical plots but numbered sequentially

Tags: r, for-loop, pdf, plot, panel

I am trying to create a 40 page pdf document with each page containing 15 (5x3) collection tags (aka blank plots with text) with individual ID numbers from 001 to 600. The tags/plots are identical except for the ID number.

This is what I want each tag to look like:

```
plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(0, 10), ylim=c(0, 10), axes=FALSE, frame.plot=TRUE)
text(x = 0.1, y = 10,               
     "Date:")
text(x = 5, y = 10,               
     "Time:")
text(x = -0.1, y = 8,               
     "Sp:")
text(x = 5, y =8,               
     "Sex:")
text(x = -0.01, y = 6,               
     "Obs:")
text(x = 5, y = 6,               
     "Sub:")
text(x = -0.1, y = 4,               
     "PH:")
text(x = 5, y = 4,               
     "PD:")
text(x = 1, y = 2,               
     "Sun/Sh/Overcast:")
text(x = 5, y = 2,               
     "Notes:")
ID <- text(x = 10, y = 10,               
     "001") #need to loop this number so the next tag would read 002, then 003, etc.
```

I've tried running the following code to create the multipanel figure, loop the tag number so it increases sequentially, and export as a pdf; however, I run into two major issues:

(1) the tags are square not landscape and thus are very squished (i.e., no room to write in values once tags are printed)

(2) the numbers do not have the correct amount of decimal places (e.g., 1 instead of 001)

```
dev.off()
max <- 150
c <- 1
c2 <- 1
while (c<max+1){
  name <- paste("~/Desktop/test",c,".pdf",sep="")
  pdf(name)
  par(mfrow=c(5,3),pty="s",mar = c(1, 1, 1, 1))
  while (c2<16) {
    plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(0, 20), ylim=c(0, 10), axes=FALSE, frame.plot=TRUE)
    text(x = 2, y = 9.8,               
         "Date:")
    text(x = 10.5, y =9.8,               
         "Time:")
    text(x = 1, y = 8,               
         "Sp:")
    text(x = 10.5, y =8,               
         "Sex:")
    text(x = 1.5, y = 6,               
         "Obs:")
    text(x = 10.5, y = 6,               
         "Sub:")
    text(x = 1.2, y = 4,               
         "PH:")
    text(x = 10.5, y = 4,               
         "PD:")
    text(x = 3, y = 2,               
         "Sun/Sh:")
    text(x = 10.5, y = 2,               
         "Notes:")
    text(9,9,c) # number
    c <- c+1
    c2 <- c2+1
  }
  dev.off()
  c2 <- 1
}
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! Problem was plot type was square (whoops) and then added some lines to fix the number problem

```
dev.off()
max <- 600
c <- 1
c2 <- 1
while (c<max+1){
  name <- paste("~/Desktop/collection_tags/tags",c,".pdf",sep="")
  pdf(width=8,height=10, name)
  par(mfrow=c(5,3),mar = c(1, 1, 1, 1), oma = c(0,1,0,1), mex = c(0.2))
  while (c2<601) {
    plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(0, 20), ylim=c(0, 10), axes=FALSE, frame.plot=TRUE)
    text(x = 0.8, y = 9.9,
         "Date:")
    text(x = 10.5, y =9.9,
         "Time:")
    text(x = 0.4, y = 8.2,
         "Sp:")
    text(x = 10.3, y =8.2,
         "Sex:")
    text(x = 2.3, y = 6.4,
         "Sun/Sh/Ovrc")
    text(x = 10.3, y = 6.4,
         "Sub:")
    text(x = 0.45, y = 4.6,
         "PH:")
    text(x = 10.1, y = 4.6,
         "PD:")
    text(x = 0.65, y = 2.6,
         "Obs:")
    text(x = 10.7, y = 2.6,
         "Notes:")
    if (1/c>0.11){
      nnn <- paste("00",c,sep="")
    }
    if (1/c<0.11 && 1/c>0.01){
      nnn <- paste("0",c,sep="")
    }
    if (1/c<=0.01){
      nnn <- c
    }
    text(19.7,9.8,nnn) # number
    c <- c+1
    c2 <- c2+1
  }
  dev.off()
  c2 <- 1
}
```